# Calculate Point position relative to origin when image is rotated

Tags: opencv, rotation, translation

I have a robot-arm here with a camera attached. The camera is fixed to the arm and takes photos in the arms rotation / position.
I use opencv to detect certain points within the image and need to translate my detected coordinates back to the coordinate system of my robot-arm. (To move over them)
I'm struggling to figure out how to transform my points (all the given information is: Origin of my arms coordinate system, arm position and point position inside the image)
Here is an image (hopefully) explaining what I want to achieve:

[image: Robo Arm Image]

In Addition I need to subtract X units from my arms length, since the pickup tool is on the tip of the arm and the camera before it.
This however should be possible by transforming the coordinates to angle+length, subtracting X and transforming them back.

Comment: Do you know the point position according to the origin before image rotation?

Comment: I know the position of the arm / center of camera relative to the arms origin (0,0).

Comment: if you describe this position by  a homography, your camera rotation is just another homography that has to be multiplied from the right direction.

Comment: robotics question. kinematics. you'll need matrices. did you expect that?

Comment: I would be happy if someone could give me a hint what calculation I would have to perform (an how). I know I can use atan2 to get the angle, and with cv2.getRotationMatrix2D and cv2.warpAffine I was able to rotate the whole image, but I plan to process the original image and translate the calculated points afterwards for better results

Comment: if you transform your unrotated pixel position pt by T*pt to your origin coordiante system, you can transform the same pixel by T*R*pt or T*R^-1*pt (depending on which direction your getRotationMatrix2D  is), where R is the 3x3 rotation matrix.